# Как найти исполняемый файл Flatpak-приложения?

Tags: linux, flatpak

Я использую Pop!_OS и почти все приложения это flatpak. Команда whereis ничего не показывает. Как мне например узнать путь до исполняемого файла текстового редактора Atom?

Мне это нужно, потому что в FileZilla нужно прописать путь до исполняемого файла текстового редактора, что бы открывать файлы php, js, и тд.

Answer (score 1):

Вначале нужно посмотреть, что есть установленного

```
flatpac list --app
```

Возможно, Вы сразу найдете атом, а может нужно будет помедитировать и запустить без `--app`.

Теперь, когда имя известно, можно попробовать запустить с консоли это приложение. Вот, к примеру, как запускать Gimp

```
flatpak run org.gimp.GIMP
```

Если запускается и работает - можно прописывать эту строку и все.

Детали:
https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/using-flatpak.html

Раз FileZilla такая хитрая, тогда можно сделать в два подхода.

Создайте маленький текстовый документ, в котором напишите такое

```
#!/bin/bash
flatpak run io.atom.Atom $1
```

и сделайте этот файл исполняемым. Вот такого монстра оно должно принять.

Comment: Спасибо, нашел, но FileZilla отказывается принимать команду :)
Я написал "flatpak run io.atom.Atom" 
А в ответ получил: Выбранный редактор не существует.

Comment: Вместо `$1` возможно лучше `"$@"`?

Comment: Да, скорее всего так может быть лучше.